# Problems implementing Intel Realsense and SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2, realsense

as title, I'm having problems trying to make SDL2 display frames from realsesense pipeline. I have no clue how to extract data from the frameset and process it in order to make it works with SDL2. I'm programming in C++. I've read all the documentation on Intel SDK website and tried a lot of different approches, nothing worked so far.

Here's some code I've wrote on a new project:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    window window(1280, 720, "Tecnos Depth Cam Demo");

    rs2::colorizer color_map;

    rs2::pipeline pipe;
    pipe.start();

    while (true)
    {
        rs2::frameset data = pipe.wait_for_frames().apply_filter(color_map);

        // Process data to work with SDL2 renderer (my problem)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I managed to do it. Simply create a texture with SDL_CreateTexture and update it with the pixels data from get_data() function of Realsense library each frame. The tricky part is that you have to define a pixel format with:

```
SDL_DEFINE_PIXELFORMAT(SDL_PIXELTYPE_PACKED8, SDL_PACKEDORDER_XBGR, SDL_PACKEDLAYOUT_8888, BITS_PER_PIXEL, BYTES_PER_PIXEL)
```

Here a little code demo that I wrote on porpuse to show you:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>

#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 1280
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 720

#define BITS_PER_PIXEL 24
#define BYTES_PER_PIXEL 3

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Init

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    // Declarative section

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Texture* textureCamera = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_DEFINE_PIXELFORMAT(SDL_PIXELTYPE_PACKED8, SDL_PACKEDORDER_XBGR, SDL_PACKEDLAYOUT_8888, BITS_PER_PIXEL, BYTES_PER_PIXEL), SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    rs2::pipeline camera;
    rs2::frameset frames;

    // Executive section

    camera.start();

    // Loop

    while (true)
    {
        // Do whatever you like there

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        // ...

        frames = camera.wait_for_frames();

        Uint8* pixels = (Uint8*)(frames.get_color_frame().get_data());

        SDL_UpdateTexture(textureCamera, NULL, pixels, frames.get_color_frame().get_bytes_per_pixel() * WINDOW_WIDTH);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, textureCamera, NULL, NULL);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I hope I helped someone in trouble like me. For any question just ask me, I'll be more than happy to help! Lastly thanks to the stackoverflow community to always help even when it doesn't!